# Frequency formula in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am just trying to figure a way to get the frequency of occurrence of a number within a large array, not the freq of the number in the array belonging to a range. 
Eg, how many times does the number 38 appear in the array below.

```
6   14  29  30  45
    19      38  49


3   15  29  33  41
6   17      35  44
    19      38  47
```

Is there a formula I can use? I have the numbers in separate columns which I am not able to paste here; they also have blank cells in between - should they be in contiguous cells?  My array is large and has to do with a number of weekly payments.

Going by what I read on frequency formula tips on the blog I am a rudimentary user of excel. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of "38" in your array:

If you have the numbers in cells A1:A10, the formula is `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,38)`

It should not matter if you have blanks in between as long as they are, in fact, blank.